# How to fail maven build if newer version of dependency exists in repository?

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Well, the problem is that I want maven to check dependency version on build and warn me if there are any newer dependency versions (in fact - notify me if I use an outdated version of some module). My maven module A has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And `com.example.mycompany:commons` module in fact can already have `1.0.4` version. Is there any way to check version of the dependency in repo and fail the build if newer version is already available.

I hope that `versions-maven-plugin` can make it. But I can not find appropriate configuration.

Comment: Have you checked [versions-maven-plugin:display-dependency-updates](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html) goal? This can be used to create a report and might be parsed to achieve what you like?

Comment: In fact I use the one with custom enforcer rule as @spacetrucker mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved with the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/). You have to create your own [custom rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html), because non of the [standard rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html) seem to match your needs.

The notion of the rule you are going to implement should be *enforce dependencies are up to date*. To implement the check you could get some inspiration by the versions-maven-plugin you mention.

Comment: @revenforv Any chance you want to publish this custom rule? I would love to use it myself.

Comment: @xnickmx Unfortunately, no. We had no time for that custom rule and so decided to use "manual check and change version" approach.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using source control and a continuous integration server (which is a safe assumption) you can:

1. use the [versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and let it modify the pom
2. then use the [scm:check-local-modification](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/check-local-modification-mojo.html) or the release plugin as the release plugin IIRC checks for local modifications.

Here is an example checking for the latest parent pom:

```
mvn versions:update-parent scm:check-local-modification -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

Comment: The default value of [`allowSnaphots`](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html#allowSnapshots) is already `false`.