# Maven : fail build if

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'd like to do some automatic checks before releasing an artifact. Failing build if :

- newer release version of dependency exists
- overriden dependency management version
- used dependency isn't in a whitelist
- duplicate declared dependency (like manual dependency:analyze-duplicate)

[Versions maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) is a manual solution.

Maven enforcer seems to be a valid solution ([How to fail maven build if newer version of dependency exists in repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463116/how-to-fail-maven-build-if-newer-version-of-dependency-exists-in-repository))

But the [standard rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/) don't do the job.

I'm looking for more enforcer rules before considering writing mines. Found these :

- [Pedantic POM Enforcers](https://github.com/ferstl/pedantic-pom-enforcers)
- [Extra Enforcer Rules](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/)

Are there more?

Comment: Duplicate declared dependencies produce a warning. Can be found by that. In relationship with a CI solution like Jenkins you could fail the build for such things. The enforcer `bannedDependencies` will help with used dependency isn't whitelist.

Comment: Yes these are valid solution, thanks. Waiting to see if someone already made or found a rule to check and fail build if newer version exists.

Comment: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MENFORCER-190